# How to add 0's into two dimensional list using list comprehension in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert this for loop into "list comprehension" format if possible:

This loop adds 0 into two dimensional list

```
test_list = [['string1'],['string2'],['string3']]
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    test_list[i].insert(1, 0)
```

output:

```
test_list = [['string1',0],['string2',0],['string3',0]]
```

I've tried this but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
test_list = [test_list[i].insert(1, 0) for i in range(len(test_list))]
```

Comment: `test_list = [x + [0] for x in test_list]`? `test_list[i].insert(1, 0)` returns nothing so you just get a big list of nothing.

Comment: That  was fast :-). Thank you very much it works perfect.

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions to mutate lists. While you can sometimes get it to work, it's at the very best misleading and wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `list.insert()` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`, so you will end up with a list of `None`s which are return values from all `.insert()`s.

List comprehension format is not adequate for what you want, because it is designed to create new lists, and you seem to want to modify the list in-place. If you want to create new lists instead, you can use this:

```
test_list = [sublist + [0] for sublist in test_list]
```

this works because the `+` operator on lists creates and returns a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question "what's the reason?"

The line

```
 test_list = [test_list[i].insert(1, 0) for i in range(len(test_list))]
```

means "make a list of the return values of this expression".

The return value of the expression `[].insert()` is None.  `test_list` will be set to a list of Nones.